# Стилизация дочерних элементов

Tags: wpf, xaml

Есть стиль

```html
<Style x:Key="menu_button" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Label Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

его нужно применить к кнопкам.

```html
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Создать тест" Style="{DynamicResource menu_button}"/>
    <Button Content="Тесты" Style="{DynamicResource menu_button}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Как сделать чтобы не прописывать стиль к каждой кнопке, а указать его в StackPanel. Ведь это будет очень утомительно

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource menu_button}"/>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Button Content="Создать тест"/>
    <Button Content="Тесты"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Вам нужно будет, возможно, включить xaml со стилем `menu_button`.

---

Если у вас много стилей, которые вы хотите включать в определённых местах, можно вынести их в общий файл с ресурсами:

```
<!-- StylesAsDefault.xaml -->
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource menu_button}"/>
    <!-- и другие стили здесь -->

</ResourceDictionary>
```

... и использование в коде:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="StylesAsDefault.xaml"/>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Button Content="Создать тест"/>
    <Button Content="Тесты"/>
</StackPanel>
```